# Multi-language site. Set routing's rules

Tags: laravel, routes, localization

I was created this simple routing

```php
Route::group(['prefix' => '{lang}'], function(){
    Route::get('/hello', function($lang){
    App::setlocale($lang);
        return view('welcome');
    });
});
```

It works of course, but in this example I returned only view. I prefer returned controller's method so in my previous project I realize routing in this way:

```php
Route:get('/hello', [
    'uses' => 'MyController@myMethod',
    'as' => 'myMethod'
]);
```

How can I use localization and returned controller's method.

Answer (score 0):

You can implement it through the Accept-Language header or the parameter that will determine which language, for example **/route/{language}**. Next, send a request to the rout, which will call the method in the controller and already in the method to check - which language to use.

Another option is to create multiple routines for multiple languages. And ask for rows depending on the language. There is a minus, if many languages ​​are used, you need to create a lot of routes

Comment: Could you show me some example? Like i show in my post, I have a group where I defined lang variable. How i can call method with this parameter (used language)?